# How to pass a query string in the NavigateUrl of a hyperlink in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink

I want to use a query string in the NavigateUrl property of a Hyperlink in Visual Studio (2013 Premium). When I click on the hyperlink I want to go to another page and pass information to that page (a group ID number). I have tried putting this in the NavigateUrl property of the hyperlink:

```
"MessageBoxAlpha.aspx?groupID=" + groupIdFromQueryString
```

but that didnt work. Then I tried putting this in the NavigateUrl property:

```
GetUrl()
```

and in the code behind I put this:

```
public string GetUrl() 
 { 
     string url = "MessageBoxAlpha.aspx?groupID=" + groupIdFromQueryString; 
     return url; 
 }
```

but it didnt work either. I know I can do this no problem with a button and just add a click event but I want to use a hyperlink for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can try putting it up like this :

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Details.aspx?Id={0}&Name={1}&Country={2}",
                    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Id").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Country").ToString())) %>'
                    Text="View Details" />
```

One more way to do it would be as this :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="addDevelopmentPlan" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/manager/uploadTrainingPlan.aspx?id=<% RequestQueryString[“id”]">link</asp:HyperLink>
```

and set the `Request.Querystring` on your `PageLoad` or wherever you want to.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic, but I did this in a GridView

`<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Vendor/Details.aspx?id=" + Eval("VendorId") %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VendorName") %>' />`

Comment: For ASP.NET 2.0 you need to add the .ToString() such as <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Vendor/Details.aspx?id=" + Eval("VendorId").ToString() %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VendorName") %>' />